# Is it legal / good to put function prototype of a function defined in a different source (not header) file?

Tags: c++, static, extern, linkage, function-prototypes

I'm not sure whether my description describes the issue appropriately. I found this when I try to understand external linkage and internal linkage. Say I have a project containing 2 files:

```
//A.cpp
#include <iostream>
void doSomething();
int main()
{
    doSomething();
    return 0;
}

//B.cpp
#include <iostream>
void doSomething()
{
    std::cout << "Doing it" << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Note that neither of the two files is a header. They merely provide 2 translation units.

I'm astonished to find that this can compile and work correctly. I'm used to writing codes like this to avoid the multi-definition error when I have the same utility function (like linear interpolation) in different files:

```
//A.cpp
#include <iostream>
static void doSomething()
{
    std::cout << "Doing it" << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
int main()
{
    doSomething();
    return 0;
}


//B.cpp
#include <iostream>
static void doSomething()
{
    std::cout << "Doing it" << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
/* some other functions that call doSomething() */
```

This is obviously redundant, and the approach above seems to solve it. 
But I wonder is this really an accepted style? One cannot even find the definition of the function without the help of an IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first block of code is legal but it is not good practice. It's better to create a `.h` file where you put function prototype and `#include` the `.h` file in all the `.cc` files that use the function.

```
//B.h
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H
void doSomething();
#endif

//A.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "B.h"
int main()
{
    doSomething();
    return 0;
}

//B.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "B.h"

void doSomething()
{
    std::cout << "Doing it" << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Ah yes. Putting function prototype there is actually equivalent to including a header containing only that prototype. Didn't realize it. Thank you!

Comment: It is not just equivalent, but actually *the same*. The pre-processor inlines this so that by the time it's compiled it looks exactly the same whether you saved to a separate file or not.

Answer (score 0):

`static` keyword means that this function, object or variable is available only in that translation unit, that is usually one cpp file. You can have multiple `static doSomething` functions across many cpp files.

About linkage. In order to use function, it is enough to provide prototype. That is usually done in h files, but you can provide function prototype of non static function also manualy in place. h files are just protypes that are used to define how functionslooks-like on order for c files to use them. As I said, you can provide protoypes also other way. It is up to linker to link this functions together.

Comment: @NeilKirk `static void doSomething()`

Comment: @Zéychin He knows what the static keyword means. He wants to know why the code without static works.